# Unable to get AWS secret using aws-sdk - I either get missing credentials error and an object

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sdk-js, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to get an AWS secret I need using the aws-sdk in a JS function but I keep getting an error about a missing credentials in config or a request object, this is the code I am using:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("get_secret", () => {
Cypress.env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'REMOVED') 
Cypress.env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 'REMOVED') 
Cypress.env('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN', 'REMOVED') 

  var AWS = require("aws-sdk"),
    region = "REMOVED",
    secretName = "REMOVED",
    secret,
    decodedBinarySecret;

  // Create a Secrets Manager client
  var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region,
  });

  client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code === "DecryptionFailureException")
        // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw err;
      else if (err.code === "InternalServiceErrorException")
        // An error occurred on the server side.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw err;
      else if (err.code === "InvalidParameterException")
        // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw err;
      else if (err.code === "InvalidRequestException")
        // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw err;
      else if (err.code === "ResourceNotFoundException")
        // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
        throw err;
    } else {
      // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
      // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
      if ("SecretString" in data) {
        secret = data.SecretString;
      } else {
        let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, "base64");
        decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString("ascii");
      }
    }

    return client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: "REMOVED" }).promise();

  });
});
```

Calling this I get `config.js:390 Uncaught (in promise) CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`

If I replace `return client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: "REMOVED" }).promise();` with `cy.wrap(client.getSecretValue("REMOVED")).as("key1");` it yields a request object but I can't see my secret anywhere in it.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the credentials directly to the client like this:

```js
const client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
  region: region,
  accessKeyId: 'abcdefghi',
  secretAccessKey: 'abcdefghi123456789',
  sessionToken: 'abcd1234'
});
```

or better, use the [`AWS.Config Class`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html) before creating the client:

```js
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'abcdefghi',
  secretAccessKey: 'abcdefghi123456789',
  sessionToken: 'abcd1234'
})
```

According to the Cypress documentation for [`Cypress.env`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env.html#Syntax), OS-level environment variables are different from Cypress environment variables:

> In Cypress, “environment variables” are variables that are accessible via Cypress.env. These are not the same as OS-level environment variables. However, it is possible to set Cypress environment variables from OS-level environment variables.

This means that they won't be picked up by the AWS SDK.

For more info on how to set credentials in the SDK, see [Setting Credentials in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html).

Comment: Yes I think that works, I now get a message about the token being expired, I'll have to wait until I'm back at work tomorrow to generate a new token. Can I ask a stupid question so I don't ask one in the future? How did you figure out the answer? I'm new to using AWS so what was it you read or where did you know to look to tell you that you could pass the vars to the client?

Comment: I've just generated a new token and now I get a different error instead `json.js:52 Uncaught (in promise) InvalidSignatureException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`

Comment: I'm confused now, I generated another token now when I run the code nothing happens. I've added some console prints and it prints them all up to the line `var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({`  after that none of the lines print out and I don't get any errors. If I mess up the token or secret id then I get an error saying they are wrong

Comment: Ignore me I was being stupid, I've been making so many changes I didn't release I had a closing brace in the wrong place. `var x = client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }).promise()` this now works thank you for the help!